# It is not possible when using the TaxonomyFilterGenerator to set the title of the refinement category

Tags: taxonomy, refinement-panel, refiner

It is not possible when using the TaxonomyFilterGenerator to set the title of the refinement category to whatever we want to appear in the refinement panel, as it now has to match the term set name. This also means the “Any…” link under the refinement title also uses this new title.

Is there a way around this, I must have a custom Title here, any suggjestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done in the xsl (if you have a custom one load it) or do it directly in the web part editor:

```
  <xsl:if test="string-length($DisplayName) &gt; 0">
    <div class="ms-searchref-categoryname">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$DisplayName  = 'Editor Keywords'">
          NewName
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayName"/>              
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
```

Basicly all in refiners title and categories etc can be custemised here...

or